# Uninstalling Rails_admin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-admin

I was using rails_admin for one of my apps which seemed to work great.

However, I need a little more customization. I deleted everything from rails_admin (`gem`, `rails_admin.rb`, and all of the code I manually put in). When I run `heroku run rake db:migrate` I get this error:

```
uninitialized constant RailsAdmin
/app/config/initializers/rails_admin.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
```

I removed `rails_admin.rb` prior and I still get this error.

I'm not sure what the steps are.

Routes.rb

Regalapp::Application.routes.draw do

```
match "/profile" => "profiles#show"
get "static_pages/invoice"
match "/invoice" => "static_pages#invoice"

get "static_pages/resources"
match "/resources" => "static_pages#resources"

resources :profiles
resources :activities
```

authenticated :user do 
    root :to => 'home#index'
  end
  root :to => "home#index"
  resources :users

end

Comment: Did you have restarted you server? may you post your routes.rb ?

Comment: Can you reproduce it on your local environment? If not, please ensure that the files were deleted in the git repository.

Comment: Thank you for the tips. I think I am just going to rebuild the app. Seems like I messed something up in the process of deleting this. Thanks for your suggestions tho!

Answer (score 6):

```
rails destroy rails_admin:install
```

Comment: It worked nicely, but didn't removed all related files, so I still had to find and remove some additional files.

Comment: @Jonauz rails_admin only creates one file: config/initializers/rails_admin.rb and change the file config/routes.rb. If you wanna uninstall de gem, that, is another history...